Postgresql database went from 56 Gb to 185 using one query
we are using Pgadmin 15 to manage our database and yesterday, we launched a basic sql query. I waited for 10 min and the result was a bit strange. I got the message "sql state : 53100" which is relative to disk space. I investigated and found that are db went from 56 Gb to 185 without creating any table or something else. We managed to access to the logs, and found that message :
2024-10-08 11:11:45.979 CEST [590] LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal

2024-10-08 11:11:47.925 CEST [590] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 1 removed, 32 recycled; write=1.817 s, sync=0.108 s, total=1.947 s; sync files=1, longest=0.108 s, average=0.108 s; distance=531924 kB, estimate=548169 kB

2024-10-08 11:11:48.036 CEST [590] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (3 seconds apart)

2024-10-08 11:11:48.036 CEST [590] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".

This message appears every 2 seconds. The main thing is that everytime, it says "estimate = 543... kb.
Could this be the main issue ? What are the solution to bring back to my 56 Gb database ?
We've tried nothing since we are not database enginners.

Either your "query" is writing lots of data, or something else is.

Advice: hire a DBA
